# Unable to find the files in the Bundle

Tags: objective-c

During developing an IOS application in Xcode4, I have added a data folder into the app bundle by dragging the folder and in order to reach this folder I've written:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *folderPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s/myDataFolder",([bundlePath UTF8String]),nil];
```

However, I can not reach `folderPath` and its contents.

Comment: @trojanfoe, edited the question, dragging entire folder

Comment: Check that `myDataFolder` is actually in the app bundle.

Comment: There are no folders in the bundle. Just reach the file with its name.

Comment: @Desdenova is depends on how you added the files to your project. If have selected create groups then yes, if you have selected create folders then you have folders in your bundle.

Comment: @rckoenes I'll look in to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit wierd, why make an UTF8String from the bundle path? You can just use the `bundlePath` directly in your format:

```
NSString *folderPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myDataFolder", bundlePath];
```

More correct would be:

```
NSString *folderPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDataFolder"];
```

This will make sure that all the correct directory separator are added.

And if you are after just one file:

```
NSString *folderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"somefile" ofType:@"sometype" inDirectory:@"myDataFolder"];
```

---

Just make sure you add the folder as a folder and not groups to you project. If you have selected groups then you can get the file path with :

```
NSString *folderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"somefile" ofType:@"sometype"];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a folder to an app, it does not preserve the folder's structure/hierarchy, it just adds files to the bundle. You have to remove your folder name from code and it's going to work

```
NSString *folderPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s/",([bundlePath UTF8String]),nil];
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that the bundle does not keep the folders, Thanks.

Comment: @yucelbayram your statement is not true, you can add folder to your Application bundle. When you drag the folder over in your project just select add as folder and not a groups. Then the foler will be added to you apps bundle.